# Scroll view Issue once long form validated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-scrollbar

We have created a sign-up page with scroll view.The page is scrolling well but when we validate page w/o enter a single entry. All error message get on screen. Now when focused on the bottom of the screen we can't slide page TOP of the screen, because of error focus already set on bottom.  Same problem occurs when focus set on top of the screen and we'll try to go at bottom.